# R - Error in fromJSON(raw.data) : incomplete list

Tags: r, api, rjson

I'm trying to read API data from the BLS into R. I am using the Version 1.0 that does not require registration and is open for public use.

Here is my code:

```
url <-"http://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v1/timeseries/data/LAUCN040010000000005"
raw.data <- readLines(url, warn = F)

library(rjson)

rd <- fromJSON(raw.data)
```

And here is the error message I receive:

```
Error in fromJSON(raw.data) : incomplete list
```

If I just try to go to the url in my webrowser it seems to work (pull up a JSON webpage). Not really sure what is going on when I try to get this into R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you've used `readLines`, the object returned is a vector of length 4:

```
length(raw.data)
```

You can look at the individual pieces via:

```
raw.data[1]
```

If you stick the pieces back together using `paste`

```
fromJSON(paste(raw.data, collapse = ""))
```

everything works. Alternatively,

```
jsonlite::fromJSON(url)
```

Comment: Thanks csgillespie, your solution works great!

Out of curiosity, the syntax on your last piece of code, is that basically saying from the jsonlite package use the fromJSON function on the variable url?

That works as well (although the output is slightly different). I'm surprised that works without me having to load the jsonlite package (library(jsonlite)).  I have that package installed but not loaded.

Comment: Yes. It's the same as `rjson::fromJSON`. It just avoids loading the package (and hence all associated functions).