# Error with fromJSON command in r

Tags: r

Related to this question. 
[R - Error in fromJSON(raw.data) : incomplete list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36799124/r-error-in-fromjsonraw-data-incomplete-list/47731776#47731776)

This `jsonlite::fromJSON(url)` does not work for me.

Am I using it correctly? I am getting this error message. Any suggestions. I can open the url.

```
cc <- jsonlite::fromJSON("https://...../")
```

> Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘jsonlite’

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the package jsonlite to use it

```
install.packages("jsonlite", repos="http://cran.r-project.org")
```

and include the libraries

```
library(jsonlite)
library(httr)
```